# When using JSTL forEach the array prints the String.toString() and not actual string value

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I have the following code:

```
String[] columnHeaders = {"Banana", "Apple", "Carrot", "Orange", "Lychee", "Permisson"};

<c:forEach var="header" items="<%= columnHeaders%>">
    <td>
        <c:out value="${header}" />
    </td>
</c:forEach>
```

When the JSP is executed, the following values get printed:

```
org.apache.commons.el.ImplicitObjects$7@6ac86ac8 
org.apache.commons.el.ImplicitObjects$7@6ac86ac8 
...
```

It appears to me that the memory value is being printed and not the value contained in each string.
What am I missing here?

Comment: Don't use `header` as a var name

Comment: @Qwerky It would appear that the quick and fast answer was to not use `header` as the var name, once I changed that and still kept my old code, it worked.  Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're referencing the `items` value incorrectly. Taglibs/EL and *scriptlets* does not share the same variable scope. You're basically printing `columnHeaders.toString()` in the `items` attribute and telling `c:forEach` to iterate over it. Instead, you need to put it in the request scope (preferably by a servlet) and use EL `${}` the normal way:

```
<%
    String[] columnHeaders = {"Banana", "Apple", "Carrot", "Orange", "Lychee", "Permisson"};
    request.setAttribute("columnHeaders", columnHeaders);
%>

<c:forEach var="columnHeader" items="${columnHeaders}">
    <td>
        <c:out value="${columnHeader}" />
    </td>
</c:forEach>
```

Also, `${header}` is an reserved EL variable referring to the request header map (see [implicit objects in EL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html#bnaij)), you'd need to rename it to something else such as `${columnHeader}` in the above example.

#### See also:

- [Our EL tag wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, table headers needs to be represented in HTML by `<th>`, not `<td>`.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. I tried what you said and I still get `columnHeaders.toString()` value of `org.apache.commons.el.ImplicitObjects$7@75b875b8 `

Comment: As for using `<th>` over `<td>`, I know, but it's old code that I've inherited and I'm lax to upgrade it, cause it'll be _a lot_ of updates everywhere.  ;)  You have a keen eye.

Comment: Please see updated answer, you need to rename `var="header"`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I noticed that it still didn't work as per your suggestion and what did work was the comment that @Qwerky provided. Is there a way to give him credit for this?

Comment: That's one mistake, your other mistake is that you attempted to reference the variable by *scriptlet* instead of EL.

Comment: Okay, I get it. But is referencing a variable by scriplet instead of EL incorrect? I'm not trying to be difficult, but it didn't appear as a wrong move to me. But I guess for consistency sake, I will go with EL instead of using `<%= varName %>`

Comment: The `<%= foo %>` basically does `out.println()` on the `foo` object.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5988/discussion-between-ruepen-and-balusc)

Answer (score 2):

This thread is pretty old but thought it would be useful nonetheless.

If you are not obligated to use `String[]` , you could use `Collection<String>` or `List<String>`.

If you do that, you won't have to put a variable in the request scope.

For example, something like the following should work:

```
List<String> columnHeaders = Arrays.asList("Banana", "Apple", "Carrot", "Orange", "Lychee", "Permisson");

<c:forEach var="columnHeader" items="${columnHeaders}">
    <td>
        <c:out value="${columnHeader}" />
    </td>
</c:forEach>
```